# XCode build with Azure Pipelines for Ionic Capacitor App (no such module 'Capacitor')

Tags: ionic-framework, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, capacitor, xcodebuild

I have a question about running a xcode build with azure pipelines on an ionic capacitor app.

The ionic and capacitor stuff is working fine. But with the Xcode build part I have a problem. The modules are not found.

At the bottom you can find my pipe. When I run this I got following error message:

```
/Users/runner/work/1/s/ProjectName/MobileApp/ProjectName/ios/App/App/AppDelegate.swift:2:8: no such module 'Capacitor'
```

Anyone that has an idea what could be the issue?

```
jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  pool:
    vmImage: macos-latest
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: NodeTool@0
    displayName: Use Node 16.x
    inputs:
      versionSpec: 16.x
      checkLatest: true
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Install global ionic and npx
    inputs:
      script: npm install -g @ionic/cli
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Npm install & ionic build in App Folder
    inputs:
      script: "npm install \nionic build"
      workingDirectory: ProjectName/MobileApp/ProjectName
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Create iOS App
    inputs:
      script: "npx cap add ios \nnpx cap sync ios"
      workingDirectory: ProjectName/MobileApp/ProjectName
  - task: CocoaPods@0
    displayName: pod install
    inputs:
      cwd: ProjectName/MobileApp/ProjectName/ios/App
  - task: Xcode@5
    displayName: Xcode build
    inputs:
      signingOption: auto
      teamId: XXXXXXXX
      cwd: ProjectName/MobileApp/ProjectName/ios/App/App
```

Comment: What happens when you build via xcode locally?

Comment: Locally everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this same error and had to specify the Xcode@5 task input

```
xcWorkspacePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ios/App/App.xcworkspace'
scheme: 'App'
```